# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to convert my saved model to a tflite model, the saved model is saved on my desktop, however when I try and run this code:
I gen an error -

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/model00000014.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}.
```

Not sure what the problem is.

```
import tensorflow as tf

saved_model_dir = "r"C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/model00000014.h5""
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to convert a `.h5` Keras model to a TFLite model, make sure you use `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model()` method, as described in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model),

```
model = tf.keras.models.load( "C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/model00000014.h5" )
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( model )
open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ).write( converter.convert() )
```

In case of a [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model), use `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` and mention the file path of the directory of the SavedModel,

```
saved_model_dir = 'path/to/savedModelDir'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
```

> You're providing a Keras Model to the `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` method, which might be causing an error.